# Computing $\int_{(1-q)^{n-1}}^1 x\left(x^\frac{1}{n-1}-1\right)^ndx $.

Tags: integration

I'm at a loss how to compute $$\int_{(1-q)^{n-1}}^1 x\left(x^\frac{1}{n-1}-1\right)^ndx. $$ Elsewhere I asked how to compute the limit of a similar expression. It would be much better, however, to be able to solve the intregral for any $n$ and not just the limit case. How can I solve this integral? Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: What are you asking? You want to find the value of this integral, but are you sure that this have a non numerical solution? or you just want to know whether there is a solution or not?

Comment: Is there a reason to believe there is a closed form?

Comment: Have you tried $x=y^{n-1}?$ When $n>0$ is an integer, it becomes a rational polynomial in $q.$ When $q=1,$ I think it becomes $$\dfrac{(-1)^n}{3n\binom{3n-1}{n}}$$

Comment: @MarcosEscartínFerrer If there exists a closed form solution, I'd like to find it.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Substituting yields $$ \int_{(1-q)^{n-1}}^1 (n-1) y^{2n-3}(y-1)^n dy, $$ if I'm not mistaken. Indeed, $n\in \mathbb{N}_{+}$. Can you elaborate, how this turns into a rational polynomial?

Comment: You should fix the bounds off your integral in the substitution: $$\int_{1-q}^1$$ @Jeff

Comment: But my integral value when $q=1$ was wrong. It is something like that.

Comment: It should be, when $q=1:$ $$ \frac{(-1)^{n}(n-1)}{(3n-2)\binom{3n-3}n}$$